# Alternative Method from c to c++

Tags: c++, c, url-rewriting, scanf

Is there an alternative way of rewriting this same script in C++ w/o using the `scanf` or `printf` functions?
Thanks!

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main( int argc, char * argv[], char* env[]) {
    char quer[222];

    printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");

    scanf("%s",quer);
    printf("%s\n",quer);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why ? Apart from the easily fixable buffer overflow, what's wrong with this code ?

Comment: main accetps either no arg or 2 args. as per standard.

Comment: @Nyan - the standard also allows other implementation-defined signatures for `main()`. Having a third parameter point to an environment bock is very common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

    std::string quer;
    std::getline(std::cin, quer);
    std::cout << quer << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This? (Note: this code has not been compiled or tested.)

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {
    std::string quer;
    std::cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
    std::cin >> quer;
    std::cout << quer << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C++ iostream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string quer;
    cout << "Content-type: text/plain" << endl;
    cin >> quer;
    cout << quer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just to point out. you state "using namespace std" and then in the code you sometimes specifically reference a type, i.e. `std::string` but in other times you don't specifically reference it. i.e. `cin` and `cout`. I'd recommend doing it all one way or the other. Particularly like @Mike Seymour did in the above answer.

Comment: cleaned answer up to be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the platform, but on Unix (or any platform where a newline is `\n`), this should be bug-compatible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char quer[222];

    puts("Content-type: text/plain\n");

    gets(quer);
    puts(quer);
    return 0;
}
```

But given that a C++ solution is acceptable, I'd recommend `cin`, `string`, `getline` and `cout` for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the reason is.... but you can also use cin/cout in place of the scanf/printf you have there.